# Header with curved pointed bottom

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I need to create the bluey/green area that is shown in the picture below. It has angled sides coming down to a point that has a slight curve.

What is the best way to achieve this using *CSS*? I need to support IE9+ or IE10+ if IE9 support is not possible.

I have started a basic [demo here](http://jsbin.com/quxohogohi/edit?html,css,output) - (Don't need the content within the bluey-green area)

[image: header with curved pointed bottom]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my attempt with css only:

```
.header {
  background: #415d67;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;

}
.header:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background: #415d67;
    width: 50%;
    bottom: -20px;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transform: skewY(-5deg);
    transform-origin: right;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    padding-right: 44px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.header:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background: #415d67;
    width: 50%;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transform: skewY(5deg);
    transform-origin: left;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    padding-left: 44px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.content {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

[JSBIN demo](http://jsbin.com/nufohexubi/1/edit?html,css,output)

You can also consider using an svg graphic.

Comment: Awsome seems to work nicely. Thank you! Only thing was I am using bootstrap and needed to add: `box-sizing: initial` to the `.header:after` and `.header:before` classes as bootstrap was using `box-sizing: border-box;` which made the the point curl up.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach would be to use an [inline svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction). The following example uses a [path element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) with a bezier curve command for the bottom curve :

```css
#header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
#header svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 100 20" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path fill="#415D67" d="M0 0 H100 V10 L52.5 19.5 Q50 20 47.5 19.5 L0 10z" />
  </svg>
  <p>Some content</p>
</div>
<p>some more content</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

linear-gradient can be usefull too : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/reYWxd

```css
.header {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #415D67 50%, transparent 51%) bottom left no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom right, #415D67 50%, transparent 51%) bottom right no-repeat, linear-gradient(to left, #415D67, #415D67) top no-repeat;
  background-size: 50.1% 30%, 50.1% 30%, 100% 70%;
  height: 105px;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  /* other makeup from here */
  display: flex;
}
h1 {
  margin: auto;
  color: turquoise;
  text-shadow:0 0 white;
}
.content {
  background: white;
  padding: 0.25em 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>whatever stands here</h1>
</div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque quia dicta fuga porro esse enim rem laudantium velit dolore doloremque. Esse, voluptatem, consequatur. Rem error unde esse. Architecto, ad, blanditiis.
</div>
```