# I want to make the marking area it responsive

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

The border 500px is fixed. How to make it responsive? it is on .page1::before area.

[image]

```
.page1{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    clear:both;
    padding:90px 0 40px 0;
    background-color:#0D9DDA;
    position:relative;
}
.page1::before{
    content:"";
    width:0;
    height:0;
    display:block;
    border-width:80px 500px 0px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#0D9DDA transparent transparent ;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    z-index:5;
}

<div class="page1"></div>
```

Comment: Basically..not with a border...a skewed pseudo-element, an SVG or perhaps something else. I'm sure this has come up before, try searching harder on SO.

Comment: Here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360411/responsive-css-triangle-with-percents-width

Comment: actually also similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392688/header-with-curved-pointed-bottom/36410667

Answer (score 0):

Change your pixels to a flexible unit like vw (viewport width) or %.
(You will need to change all of the pixel units)

So if you wanted 500px on a 1920px wide display 500/1920 ~= 26vw

Comment: Yes. The vw technique working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

setup a display size criteria say 30em, and add css code as follow. need further tweaking to get it right, of course.

```
[![/* Responsive <  30em */
@media all and (max-width:  29.9375em){

.page1{width:100%;
   height:auto;
   clear:both;
   padding:90px 0 40px 0;
   background-color:#0D9DDA;
   position:relative;
   }
.page1::before{content:"";
           width:0;
           height:0;
           display:block;
           border-width:40px 200px 0px;
           border-style:solid;
           border-color:#0D9DDA transparent transparent ;
           position:absolute;
           top:100%;
           left:0;
           z-index:5;
}
 }
/* larger display  > 30em*/
@media all and (min-width:  30em){

 .page1{width:100%;
   height:auto;
   clear:both;
   padding:90px 0 40px 0;
   background-color:#0D9DDA;
   position:relative;
   }
.page1::before{content:"";
           width:0;
           height:0;
           display:block;
           border-width:80px 500px 0px;
           border-style:solid;
           border-color:#0D9DDA transparent transparent ;
           position:absolute;
           top:100%;
           left:0;
           z-index:5;
}
}][1]][1]
```

Comment: All of the common stuff should be pulled out of the `@media` rules; such as `.page1{width:100%; height:auto;` etc. rather than duplicating it all.